# Ember template with Google Maps infoWindow

Tags: google-maps, ember.js, handlebars.js

I am trying to pull an existing template in Ember to use in a google map infoWindow. The google.maps.InfoWindow method takes an object with a content property set to a HTML string.

I would like to use an existing Ember template which I am using elsewhere in my app as the infoWindow content. I am having difficulty converting my template into a HTML string.

I have tried the following methods:

```
Ember.Handlebars.compile(templateName)(model.get('data'));
// Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Ember.TEMPLATES[templateName](model.get('data'));
// Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'createChildView' of undefined
```

This is all being done in my map view on the didInsertElement method.

The alternative is to create the HTML string and pass in the variables manually in the view, but that's messy and requires me to maintain two versions of the same template.

What is the correct approach for what I'm trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

Try this out. Just recently got this working in my own personal project.

Here's my infoWindow View

```
Ember.View.extend({
init: function () {
    this._super();
    this.get('parentView').registerInfoWindow(this);

    this.get('googleInitializer.library').then(function () {

        this.set('infoWindow', new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: $('<div></div>')[0]
        }));

        google.maps.event.addListener(this.get('infoWindow'), 'closeclick', function () {
            this.set('open', false);
        }.bind(this));

    }.bind(this));
},
classNames: 'hidden',
tagName: 'div',
map: Ember.computed.alias('parentView.map'),
marker: Ember.computed.alias('parentView.marker'),
infoWindow: null,
open: false,

onOpenChange: function () {
    if (this.get('infoWindow')) {

        if (this.get('open')) {
            this.get('infoWindow').open(this.get('map'), this.get('marker'));
        } else {
            this.get('infoWindow').close();
        }

    }
}.observes('open'),
detachedDom: null,
onWindowContentReady: function () {
    if (this.get('infoWindow') && this.get('detachedDom')) {
        this.get('infoWindow').setContent(this.get('detachedDom'));
    }
}.observes('infoWindow', 'detachedDom'),
didInsertElement: function () {
    this.set('detachedDom', this.$().detach()[0]);
}
});
```

Essentially what's happening here is that I'm detaching the dom as soon as its generated. Later when the infoWindow is ready, I set the content of the infoWindow. The html is rendered and button action events are preserved. I'm not sure what will happen if you attempt to any more advanced ember bindings. I just got this working, so I'm looking into myself.

The benefits of doing it this way, is that I can write my templates like this

```
{{#view 'google-maps' markers=fixtureCollection}}
    {{#with view.markerController}}
        {{#each}}
            {{#view 'marker' coords=this}}
                {{#view 'infoWindow'}}
                    <div>
                        <h2>Hello World</h2>
                        <button {{action 'doSomething'}}>Foo</button>
                    </div>

                {{/view}}
            {{/view}}
        {{/each}}
    {{/with}}
{{/view}}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I've only just seen it (I think my email notifications must be turned off). I'll check it out and let you know how I get on.